# extracting html data with beautiful soup is not working

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to retrieve all the row data from this website 
https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRecs.aspx?Category=awddt&TypeSrch=cq&Value=02-06-2018
this is sample html for the rows

```
  <tr class="BgWhite" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">

<td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl43_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/03JAN17/SP450017D0005.PDF" title="Link To Award/Basic Document" target="DIBBSDocuments"><img src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" alt="PDF Document" width="16" height="16" hspace="2" border="0"></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/03JAN17/SP450017D0005.PDF" title="Link To Award/Basic Document" target="DIBBSDocuments">SP450017D0005</a></span>
</td>

<td align="center" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl43_lblCage"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return openNewWindow(&quot;https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Refs/cage.aspx?Cage=0ZE15&quot;, &quot;CAGE&quot;, 475, 300)" title="Click to perform a CAGE Search">0ZE15</a></span>
</td>
<td align="right" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl43_lblTotalContactPrice">                   $2,341.94</span>
</td>

 </tr>

 <tr class="BgSilver" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">


<td align="left" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblDeliveryOrder" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/06FEB18/SP450017D0005SP450018F2293.PDF" title="Link To Delivery Order Document" target="DIBBSDocuments"><img src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" alt="PDF Document" width="16" height="16" hspace="2" border="0"></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/06FEB18/SP450017D0005SP450018F2293.PDF" title="Link To Delivery Order Document" target="DIBBSDocuments">SP450018F2293</a> <br><img src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16" height="16" hspace="1" border="0" alt="-spacer-"><span style="font-size: 9px;">» <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRec.aspx?contract=SP450017D0005&amp;dlv=SP450018F2293&amp;cnt=108" title="Delivery Order Package View" target="DIBBS">Delivery Order Package View</a></span></span>
</td>
<td align="right" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblDeliveryOrderCounter" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">108</span>
</td>

<td align="right" valign="top">
    <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblTotalContactPrice">                   $2,341.94</span>
</td>
```

I want to extract the awardids SP450017D0005 and SP450018F2293 from the html. So I tried this 
    dibbssoup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.content, 'html5lib')

```
containers1 = dibbssoup.find_all("tr", {"class": "BgWhite"})
containers2 = dibbssoup.find_all("tr", {"class": "BgSilver"})

containers = containers1 + containers2

for container1 in containers:


    for page in range(row)[3:]:
        containerid = "ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl"+str(page)+"_lblAwardBasicNumber"

        awardid = container1.find("td", {"align": "left"}).find("span", {"id":containerid})

        print(page)
        print(containerid)
        print(awardid)
        print(" ")
```

page incrementation works and containerid is correct but the output of awardid is "none". What am I doing wrongly and how can I correct it?

Comment: Use `soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['BgWhite', 'BgSilver']})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently don't see any big flaws in your code. When working with this kind of nested html tags, it is often useful to split your `find` statements up and print the result of each one of them. When you are debugging you can now clearly see which of the `find` calls failed. After solving your problems you can still recombine them and clean up your code.

To get rid of `page` and `containerid` variables you can use a function as an argument for `find` like this:

```
def basic_number_filter(tag):
    return tag.name == "span" and tag.attrs.get("id", "").endswith("_lblAwardBasicNumber")

containers = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['BgWhite', 'BgSilver']})

for container in containers:
    awardid = container.find("td", align="left").find(basic_number_filter)
    print(awardid)
```

You can find more information about this here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

When running this code with the sample html you provided, I get:

```
<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl43_lblAwardBasicNumber" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;"><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/03JAN17/SP450017D0005.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document"><img alt="PDF Document" border="0" height="16" hspace="2" src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" width="16"/></a><a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/03JAN17/SP450017D0005.PDF" target="DIBBSDocuments" title="Link To Award/Basic Document">SP450017D0005</a></span>
None
```

The second `awardid` is `None`, because

```
<tr class="BgSilver" style="border-color:Gray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
    <td align="left" valign="top">
        <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblDeliveryOrder" style="display:inline-block;width:175px;">
            <a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/06FEB18/SP450017D0005SP450018F2293.PDF" title="Link To Delivery Order Document" target="DIBBSDocuments"><img src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/icons/IconPdf.gif" alt="PDF Document" width="16" height="16" hspace="2" border="0"></a>
            <a href="https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/Awards/06FEB18/SP450017D0005SP450018F2293.PDF" title="Link To Delivery Order Document" target="DIBBSDocuments">SP450018F2293</a>
            <br><img src="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/app_themes/images/common/space.gif" width="16" height="16" hspace="1" border="0" alt="-spacer-">
            <span style="font-size: 9px;">» <a href="https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRec.aspx?contract=SP450017D0005&amp;dlv=SP450018F2293&amp;cnt=108" title="Delivery Order Package View" target="DIBBS">Delivery Order Package View</a></span>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="top">
        <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblDeliveryOrderCounter" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;">108</span>
    </td>

    <td align="right" valign="top">
        <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblTotalContactPrice">                   $2,341.94</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

contains no `span` with an `id` like `ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl43_lblAwardBasicNumber`.

Comment: how would you obtain SP450018F2293 from the tr class=BgSilver

Comment: There is always more than one way to get this information and I am not sure if this is the best or most stable one, but you can try: `container.find("td", align="left").find("span").text`. For the examples you provided this string starts with the information you want followed by a whitespace, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: i thought this will work. container.find("td", align="left").find("span"{"id":"ctl00_cph1_grdAwardSearch_ctl44_lblDeliveryOrder"}).text